# php coundown auto update issue

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, cron

```
<?php
//index.php

$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$current_min_sec = date('i:s');
$current_min = date('i');

$array_min= array(0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57);

if((int)$current_min >= 57){
    $next_slot_time = 0;
}else{
    $min = (int)$current_min;

    $newNumbers = array_filter(
    $array_min,
    function ($value) use($min) {
        return ($value > $min);
        }
    );

    $next_slot_time = reset($newNumbers);
}
?>
<div id='countdown'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    const updateWind = () => {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var valr5 = this.responseText;
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = valr5;
            
            if (valr5 == '00:00'){
                window.location = "index.php";
            }   
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "response.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("next_slot="+<?php echo $next_slot_time?>);
    };

    updateWind();
    window.setInterval(updateWind, 1000);
</script>

<?php
//response.php
$time = new DateTime();

$start_timer_time = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$end_minute = $_POST['next_slot'];

if($end_minute == 0){
    $timeHr = $time->format("H") + 1;
}else{
    $timeHr = $time->format("H");
}

$time->setTime($timeHr,$end_minute,00);
$end_timer_time = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$from_time = $start_timer_time;
$to_time = $end_timer_time;

$timefirst = strtotime($from_time);
$timesecond = strtotime($to_time);

$diffinsec=$timesecond-$timefirst;

if(gmdate("i:s",$diffinsec) == '00:30'){ 
    echo 'RUN SCRIPT HERE';
}else if(gmdate("i:s",$diffinsec) == '00:00'){ 
    echo gmdate("i:s",$diffinsec);
}else{
    echo gmdate("i:s",$diffinsec);
}

?>
```

I have a script which shows a countdown with a button and table to the users. it has following things

1] Run countdown every 3 min (exactly 20 times in one hour) 2] Show countdown timing same to all users 3] Never reset countdown on user browser refresh 4] On 00.30 button lock through js and internally another php script runs which does some calculation and updates 1 entry to the table 5] On 00.00 when time over page gets refreshed, the countdown starts again and the below table is shown with newly added entry.

This script is working fine when it is open in the browser but not working when no user is accessing this page. I want to run this countdown offline also. I am figuring out two solutions

1] Make one more script, So it will work when index.php is not open by anyone (but don't know how to track when it should run and when its should not run) 2] Make a single script like (cron) job but in that case how do I display countdown to users

I am not aware of possible vulnerabilities. Kindly share your thoughts. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: To have something run continuously cron jobs are the only solution. You would need to pass the timer to the front end from the back for higher reliability (with timestamps not minutes). So all the main timing should be on the back end, not the front. The front just does front stuff.

Comment: How do I keep updating my timer <div id='countdown'></div> because cron script will be refresh every 1 sec

Comment: You can call cron job page from ajax every x minute.

Comment: Constantly polling the server via AJAX will be very inefficient though, so you should also consider using websockets to push updates from the server

Comment: @ADyson I haven't work on websockets yet..and the problem is I have not enough time to learn it from scratch as this problem has encounter at last moment on time of deivery.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I wanted show ticking time so every second that div should be updated

Comment: @ADyson call one time ajax then use front-end for continue the time? so everytime user refresh will have right time.

Comment: Use server cron job not wp cron job since wp requires someone to visit to run crons. This may overload shared hosting so depens on how heavy tasks you run.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini It could work. Depends how accurate it needs to be in the meantime, I suppose...OP didn't say how critical that is - JS timers can get out of sync.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini You need to have periodic calls to make sure the browser is not mistimed. It is rare but can happen if the person is running the wrong setting. But yes, that was my trail of thought. Just push timestamps with critical events and server times etc on the first call, then javascript does most logic and requests what is needed. It is not the best way to make it, but it is the fastest. You can even push the data to the XML file so the javascript has to get only that file, which would ease up the server big time, and the main load would just come from the corn job itself.

Comment: what if I check user session currently present or not and if it is not present run the cron job only on that time..

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is only achieve by cron job.. Thanks guys for the support

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).